# Calculating a limit with exponential terms

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $a,b,c$ be non-negative numbers. What are the conditions on $a,b,c$ so that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[1-e^{-na}-e^{-nb}\right]^{\exp(nc)} = 1.
$$

Using the fact that
$$
\log(1+x)\geq\frac{x}{1+x}
$$
we see that
$$
\left[1-e^{-na}-e^{-nb}\right]^{\exp(nc)} \geq \exp\left\{-e^{nc}\frac{e^{-na}+e^{-nb}}{1-e^{-na}-e^{-nb}}\right\}
$$
Thus, if $c\leq\min(a,b)$ we will certainly obtain that 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[1-e^{-na}-e^{-nb}\right]^{\exp(nc)} = 1.
$$
Is there any weaker condition?